# how to use repository in typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

Steps to reproduce or a small repository showing the problem:

```
   let pid = tabla.id

    return await this.Repository.update(
      {predeterminado: false},
      {predeterminado: true, id: Not(pid)})
```

The above throws the following error: The expected type comes from property 'id' which is declared here on type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity '

If I do it with Query Builder, it works fine.

```
let pid = tabla.id

  return await this.Repository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(AlicuotasIva)
  .set({predeterminado: false})
  .where("id != :pid",{pid})
  .andWhere("predeterminado = 1")
  .execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, I'm not sure that you correctly put parameters, I'll describe them in the code comments:

```
let pid = tabla.id

return await this.Repository.update(
  {predeterminado: false}, // <-- first parameter of update method is criteria (find condition)
  {predeterminado: true, id: Not(pid)}) // <-- the second parameter is your updates
```

So, I guess, you need just to switch parameters places and it would works:

```
let pid = tabla.id

// this query means that you set 'predeterminado' to 'false' for those rows which currently 'predeterminado == true' and their 'id != pid'
return await this.Repository.update(
  {predeterminado: true, id: Not(pid)},
  {predeterminado: false}
)
```

Comment: Right, you are absolutely right. Thank you very much for your answer.